# Save an Excel PDF sheet in the same directory as my Excel file

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I've written a function that saves my Excel sheet in a PDF file in the same directory where my Excel file is. Everything was working well until I copied the same function to another sheet and after that, it prints only a part of the content. Here is my VBA function:

```
Sub stampa_ordine_pdf()
    Dim sNome As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook
        sPath = .Path
        With .Worksheets("Ordine Munters")
            sNome = "Ordine N. " & .Range("C8").Value & _
                    " del " & Format(.Range("C7").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=sPath & "\" & sNome & ".pdf", _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `On Error Resume Next` statements and see if any error messages are displayed.

Comment: I just noticed that you have `IgnorePrintAreas:=False`.  Do you have print areas set up in this sheet and is the print area the "part of the content" that is being printed?  If so, ignore them by setting `IgnorePrintAreas:=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with YowE3k, there is probably a print area set the is trimming the exported range.

```
Sub stampa_ordine_pdf()
    Dim FileName As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    With Worksheets("Ordine Munters")
        sName = "Ordine N. " & .Range("C8").Value & _
                " del " & Format(.Range("C7").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sName & ".pdf"

        .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                FileName:=FileName, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With

End Sub
```